# How to overload normal function and template function with same number of parameters?

Tags: c++, templates, vector

### What am I doing?

I am trying to implement the standard library `vector`. There is a member function called `assign()` that is overloaded as:

```
template<typename InputIterator>
void assign(InputIterator first, InputIterator last)
void assign(size_type n, const value_type& val)
void assign(std::initializer_list<value_type> il)
```

### My implementation:

```cpp
template<typename InputIterator>
void assign(InputIterator first, InputIterator last)
{
    difference_type t_ptrdiff = last - first;
    if(t_ptrdiff > m_size) reallocate(size_type(t_ptrdiff) << 1);
    for(size_type idx = 0; first != last; ++idx, ++first)
        m_base[idx] = *first;
    m_size = t_ptrdiff;
}

void assign(size_type n, const value_type& val)
{
    if(n > m_size) reallocate(n << 1);
    for(size_type idx = 0; idx != n; ++idx)
        m_base[idx] = val;
    m_size = n;
}

void assign(std::initializer_list<value_type> il)
{
    typename std::initializer_list<value_type>::size_type il_size = il.size();
    typename std::initializer_list<value_type>::iterator end = il.end();
    if(il_size > m_size) reallocate(il_size << 1);
    size_type idx = 0;
    for(typename std::initializer_list<value_type>::iterator begin = il.begin(); begin != end; ++idx, ++begin)
        m_base[idx] = *begin;
    m_size = il_size;
}
```

Also, I am pretty sure this is a terrible way to reallocate heap memory, but this is what I currently have:

```cpp
void reallocate(size_type requested_capacity)
    {
        value_type* t_base = new value_type[requested_capacity];
        m_capacity = requested_capacity;
        if(m_base == nullptr){
            m_base = t_base;
            return;
        }
        if(m_capacity < m_size)
            m_size = m_capacity;
        for(size_type idx = 0; idx < m_size; ++idx)
            t_base[idx] = m_base[idx];
        delete [] m_base;
        m_base = t_base;
    }
```

### Problem:

Everything works as expected when I call these methods using integral objects, such as:

```cpp
vector<int> v;

// This will correctly call: void assign(size_type n, const value_type& val)
vector<int>::size_type n = 7;
vector<int>::value_type val = 100;
v.assign (n, val);

// This will correctly call: void assign(InputIterator first, InputIterator last)
vector<int>::iterator it = v.begin() + 1;
v.assign (it, v.end()-1);

// This will correctly call: void assign(std::initializer_list<value_type> il)
v.assign ({1776,7,4});
```

But when I try to call `assign()` with integral literals, for example: `v.assign(7, 100)`, the compiler complains with the following error because it is matching against the templated function: `void assign(InputIterator first, InputIterator last)`:

```
In file included from main.cpp:LINE:
vector.h: In instantiation of ‘void vector<T>::assign(InputIterator, InputIterator) [with InputIterator = int; T = int]’:
main.cpp:LINE:COLUMN:   required from here
vector.h:LINE:COLUMN: error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’)
  xxx |             m_base[idx] = *first;
```

### `libstdc++` implementation:

I checked `libstdc++` implementation, and this is their function declarations:

```cpp
void assign(size_type __n, const value_type& __val);
template<typename _InputIterator>
void assign(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last);
void assign(initializer_list<value_type> __l);
```

With the standard library's `std::vector` there is no such conflict; `v.assign(7, 100)` is correctly resolved to `void assign(size_type __n, const value_type& __val)`; but not in my implementation.

### Update:

I recently learnt about `std::enable_if` and **SFINAE**, all thanks to [n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/775806/n-1-8e9-wheres-my-share-m)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73017579/18311567) below. This is how I did it:

```cpp
template<typename InputIterator>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_pointer<InputIterator>::value>::type
assign(InputIterator first, InputIterator last);
```

- It checks if `InputIterator` is actually a pointer using `std::is_pointer`; however, (correct me if I am wrong) not all iterators need to be pointers, they only need to obey certain rules (which include dereferencing, incrementing, equality comparable).
- This is the best I could do, because even though *n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m.* provided an example, I still could not figure out the correct syntax.
- Also, I ended up using `std::enable_if<>::type` for the `assign()` function's type. It did not matter here, because this function had type `void`. But what if I needed to return something. What would be the correct syntax then?
- My problem for now is solved, but if someone wants to provide an improved implementation than what I somehow ended up doing, please do not hesitate; it will be highly appreciated!

Comment: How do you declare `class vector` & `value_type` inside it? My guess is that by default, `7,100` are treated as `int` and this could be the reason, it falls back on the `template` version.

Comment: Sorry for being late, I had to go to hospital for checkup. So, `value_type` is a `typedef` alias to the `vector` template variable `T`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The overload

```
template <typename InputIterator>
void assign(InputIterator first, InputIterator last)
```

participates in overload resolution only if InputIterator satisfies LegacyInputIterator [see](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/assign).

For an implementor this means that some kind of SFINAE is necessary pre-C++20. In C++20 you can use concepts instead.

To SFINAE away non-iterators, you can do something like this

```
template <typename InputIterator>
std::enable_if_t<???> assign ...
```

where `???` is a constant expression that is only valid (and true) for InputIterator which is a LegacyInputIterator.

I will not write down the entire condition, but here is one part of it. To ensure that the dereference is defined for InputIterator, you can write

```
sizeof(*std::declval<InputIterator>()) > 0
```

This condition evaluates to true if the dereference operator is defined, and *fails substitution* if it is not defined.

Make a conjunction of all the conditions [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/InputIterator) and you should be set.

Comment: Thank you so much! Those are really amazing reads. It is funny that I read the article at [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/InputIterator) but totally missed the **LegacyInputIterator** note. Thanks once again!

Answer (score 1):

The **problem** is that both `7` and `100` are `int` literals and so the templated overload is a better match than the nontemplate version because in the nontemplate version a conversion is required from `int` to `size_type` for the first argument while in the template version there is no conversion required as `InputIterator` is deduced to be `int`.

One possible way of solving this is by adding suffix `u` after the first argument `7` or by casting first argument to `size_type`.

Below is a contrived example:

```
template<typename InputIterator>
void assign(InputIterator first, InputIterator last)  //#1
{
    std::cout<<"template version"<<std::endl;
}
void assign(std::size_t n, const int& val)           //#2
{
    std::cout<<"nontemplate versino"<<std::endl;
}
int main()
{
    assign(7,100);                                  //calls #1 as #1 is a better match
    assign(7u, 100);                                //calls #2
//          ^------------->added u
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I am wondering how the standard library `vector` class is able to call the second overloaded function, with just `assign(7, 100)`.

Comment: @akaAbdullahMateen There must be something else that is letting the standard librarys's `vector` choose the nontemplate version with `assign(7, 100)`.  I mean the standard library also follows the same basic rules that are applied when we(users) write code. Most likely cause is that we are missing some detail in the question which lets the `std::vector` chose the nontemplate version with `assign(7, 100)`. For example, in cppreference it says:  *"This overload participates in overload resolution only if InputIt satisfies LegacyInputIterator.
 "*

Comment: For example, in [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/assign) it says:  *"This overload participates in overload resolution only if `InputIt` satisfies LegacyInputIterator. Meaning the nontemplate overload can be selected because the template version don't even participate in overload resolution."*

Comment: Yep, got it! Thanks once again for so much help! I apologize once again for late replies, had to go out and do some other stuff. Nevertheless, I appreciate your response. Have a wonderful day :)